# Bootstrap Carousel - Put next and prev button on top right and closer to each other

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

Am using bootstrap 4 carousel. Am trying to change the position of next and prev button to be at top right corner but close to each other. I have managed that but i think am making a mistake in my css code since when i minimize the screen I don't see the buttons.

Html code

```
<div id="featured" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <!-- The slideshow -->
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="carousel-item active">
      <img src="one.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img src="two.jpg" >
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img src="three.jpg" >
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- Left and right controls -->
 <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#featured" data-slide="prev">
   <span class="fa fa-arrow-circle-left fa-2x" style="color:green"></span>
  </a>
  <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#featured" data-slide="next">
   <span class="fa fa-arrow-circle-right fa-2x" style="color:green"></span>
  </a>
</div>
```

my css code

```
.carousel-control-prev,
.carousel-control-next{
  width:20px;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: none;
  top:calc(-20% -25%);
  opacity:.8;
}
.carousel-control-prev{
 left:1090px !important;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`left:1090px !important` is going to cause issues once the user's viewport hits close or less than `1090px`. In retrospect, you should be able to asses why - because it is pushing it `1090px` from left.

Do something like

```
.carousel-control-prev{
  left: unset;
  right: 30px;
}
```

instead, so you can control it from the `right` since you are positioning it upper-right

```js
$('.carousel').carousel()
```

```css
.carousel {
  background: black;
}

.carousel .carousel-control-prev,
.carousel .carousel-control-next {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: none;
  top: calc(-20% -25%);
  opacity: .8;
}

.carousel .carousel-control-prev {
  left: unset;
  right: 30px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div id="featured" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <!-- The slideshow -->
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="carousel-item active">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/650x200">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/651x200">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/652x200">
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- Left and right controls -->
  <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#featured" data-slide="prev">
    <!--<span class="fa fa-arrow-circle-left fa-2x" style="color:green"></span>-->
    <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
  </a>
  <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#featured" data-slide="next">
    <!--<span class="fa fa-arrow-circle-right fa-2x" style="color:green"></span>-->
    <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
  </a>
</div>
```